# Changing tableview cells items

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have an application that contains 4 mutable arrays,i already displays one array of items in tableview cell,but i want to change the contents of the table cells in button click,i defined 4 buttons ,my need is when i click a button the tableview cells changes the array and display corresponding array items.I this possible to reuse tableview cell in a button click,my code for tableview cell below.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)aTableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_titleArray count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Each subview in the cell will be identified by a unique tag.
    static NSUInteger const kcatogeryLabelTag = 2;
    static NSUInteger const ktitleLabelTag = 3;
    static NSUInteger const kshortDiscriptionLabelTag = 4;
    static NSUInteger const knewsImageTag = 5;

    // Declare references to the subviews which will display the earthquake data.
    UILabel *catogeryLabel = nil;
    UILabel *titleLabel = nil;
    UILabel *shortDiscriptionLabel = nil;
    UIImageView *newsImage = nil;

    static NSString *kEarthquakeCellID = @"EarthquakeCellID";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kEarthquakeCellID];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // No reusable cell was available, so we create a new cell and configure its subviews.
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:kEarthquakeCellID] autorelease];

        catogeryLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(91, 3, 190, 20)] autorelease];
        catogeryLabel.tag = kcatogeryLabelTag;
        catogeryLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:20];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:catogeryLabel];

        titleLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(91, 28, 170, 14)] autorelease];
        titleLabel.tag = ktitleLabelTag;
        titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Manorama" size:10];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];

        shortDiscriptionLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(91, 50, 500, 20)] autorelease];
        shortDiscriptionLabel.tag = kshortDiscriptionLabelTag;
        shortDiscriptionLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Manorama" size:14];
        shortDiscriptionLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:shortDiscriptionLabel];

        newsImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loadingimage.jpg"]] autorelease];
        CGRect imageFrame =newsImage.frame;
        imageFrame.origin = CGPointMake(62, 2);
        newsImage.frame = imageFrame;
        newsImage.tag = knewsImageTag;
        newsImage.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:newsImage];
    } else {
        // A reusable cell was available, so we just need to get a reference to the subviews
        // using their tags.
        //
        catogeryLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kcatogeryLabelTag];
        titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:ktitleLabelTag];
        shortDiscriptionLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kshortDiscriptionLabelTag];
        newsImage = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:knewsImageTag];
    }


    // Get the specific earthquake for this row.
    Row *newsSubcatogery = [_titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     // Set the relevant data for each subview in the cell.
      catogeryLabel.text = newsSubcatogery.categoryName; 

      titleLabel.text =  newsSubcatogery.title;

      shortDiscriptionLabel.text =   newsSubcatogery.shortDescription;

      NSURL *url = [NSURL  URLWithString:newsSubcatogery.thumbImage];
      NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
      UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]; 
     // CGSize imageSize = [image size];
      [newsImage setImage:image];
      [image release], image = nil;

     return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to assigned `tag` property of table view on your button click.

```
- (IBAction) btnClick1:(id)sender
{
   tableview.tag = 200;
   [tableview reload];
}
```

now in all your table view's delegate method check the `tag` of table view like

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    if([tableView tag] == 200)
    {
        return [otherArray count];
    }
    else if ([tableView tag] == 300)
    {
        return [anotherArray count];
    }
}
```

above is sample code you have to modify it accordingly. Hope it helps you.

Comment: but i have only one tableview in uiview.i want to load different data in single tableview by using button click,is your code enough for my requirement?

Comment: you need to assign different tags of table view on different button click like btn1 then table.tag=200 , btn2 then table.tag=300 like wise..

Comment: _titleArray contains parsed xml objects,i have three more parsed arrays like this,is the value of the labels and images in tableview cells changes correspondent to the button click?

Comment: does your cell contains same number of lables,images etc ?

Comment: its worked fine for me now,but how to code if the cell contains diffrent number of labels and image?

Comment: ohhh,can u please give me some idea about to create custom cells.